# Add to variable with a button

Tags: javascript, html, variables, numbers, addition

I have a script with a javascript variable and a button, now everytime I press this button I would like the variable to raise by one, I have tried as you can see in the script below, but there are some issues, the number doesn't show and the number isn't raised by one every time the button is clicked, what is wrong?

javascript:

```
var nativeNR = 1;

function addOne() {
    nativeNR = nativeNR + 1;
}
```

html:

```
<form id="form">
    <input style="width: 500px;" type="add" id="plusButton" onclick="addOne();" />
</form>

current amount <span id="nativeNR"></span>
```

Comment: You need to set the span to show the value, in addOne() try putting document.getElementById("nativeNR").innerHTML = nativeNR;

Comment: possible duplicate of [setting content between div tags using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396590/setting-content-between-div-tags-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the number will increase by one every time you click. However you are not displaying it in the span. So to do that you can reference the element and set the nativeNR to it.

Your method should be like this

```
var nativeNR = 1;

function addOne() {
  nativeNR = nativeNR + 1;
  document.getElementById("nativeNR").innerHTML = nativeNR;
}

<form id="form">
    <input style="width: 500px;" type="button" id="plusButton" onclick="addOne();" />
</form>
```

Also there is not input `type="add"` it should be `type="button"`

```js
var nativeNR = 1;
document.getElementById("nativeNR").innerHTML = nativeNR

function addOne() {
    nativeNR = nativeNR + 1;
    document.getElementById("nativeNR").innerHTML = nativeNR;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
    <input style="width: 500px;" type="button" id="plusButton" value="add" onclick="addOne();" />
</form>

current amount <span id="nativeNR"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the add function works and the counting also works. But if the button hasn't been clicked and it is at default number which is 1, it doesn't show the number?
http://jsfiddle.net/9bfvaspj/16/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use javascript to actually put that number into the DOM.  Also, make sure that the function `addOne` isn't in an `onload` wrapper; it needs to be in the DOM itself, and declared before the `input` element that calls it.

The function would look like this:

```
var nativeNR = 1;

function addOne() {
    nativeNR = nativeNR + 1;
    document.getElementById('nativeNR').innerHTML = nativeNR;
}
```

Here's a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/yw2h5bs3/)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write the number to the span as well, now you are simply adding it to the variable in memory:

```
document.getElementById('nativeNR').innerHTML = nativeNR;
```

Also, you might want to change the input type to "button".