# Add JS to HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help in trying get what I have in my `<scripts>` onto my HTML page.

I am using the Yahoo Weather API and here is the information I have:

```
<script>
    var callbackFunction = function (data) {
        var location = data.query.results.channel.location;
        var condition = data.query.results.channel.item.condition;
        var wind = data.query.results.channel.wind;
        //I could just alert all of these to get pop ups but I am not looking for that
    }
</script>
<script src="https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20weather.forecast%20WHERE%20woeid%3D%22%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=callbackFunction"></script>
```

Now how do I get the 3 variables `location`, `condition`, `wind` into a `<div>` so that they can be displayed as HTML?

Comment: Select an element and set the innerHTML

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setting content between div tags using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396590/setting-content-between-div-tags-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```html
<div id="results"></div>
<script>
    var callbackFunction = function (data) {
        
        console.log('Data from yahoo:', data); // response from yahoo
        
        var location = 'Hello'; //data.query.results.channel.location;
        var condition = 'World'; //data.query.results.channel.item.condition;
        var wind = '!'; //data.query.results.channel.wind;
        //I could just alert all of these to get pop ups but I am not looking for that
      
        // INTERACTING WITH THE D.O.M.
        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = location + '</br>' + condition + '</br>' + wind;

    }
</script>
<script src="https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20weather.forecast%20WHERE%20woeid%3D%22%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=callbackFunction"></script>
```

Basically what we are doing here, is grabbing the page `document`, finding an element by its id `.getElementById('results')`, and setting its contained html with the `.innerHTML` property, and using `</br>` to put each result on a new line.

Comment: got it! but now when i run it, it says `unable to get property 'query' of undefined or null reference`.. but if I ignore it.. I still get the correct data?

Comment: That sounds like your "data" variable is undefined. Is your jsonp calling "callbackFunction" with the right argument? The "data.query" is not suppose to work for this example, but that's because it's not making a call to yahoo for the data, thus why I commented it out. Does that make sense?

Comment: It does make sense.. but I am using [this] (https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/#get-started) and i don't see much of a difference.. that yql interface is difficult to use.. can you see a difference?

Comment: I updated the example to retrieve the data from yahoo using the query you originally posted. As you can see, the response comes back just fine and the "data" variable is not undefined. However, some of its properties does appear to be missing (i.e. "data.query.results.channel" is valid, but "data.query.results.channel.location" is undefined). So my recommendation is, copy this example, fiddle with the query, and get it to respond back with the properties you want.

Comment: I added what you added.. the `console.log(data)` and that error message still appears

Comment: That error is not going to go away until you have the right "data". What does  console.log(data) return for you?

Comment: when I do `alert(data)`.. the alert says 'undefined'

Comment: ahh i didn't erase the `callbackFunction()` at the end.. i didn't notice that in one of your edits